# ¿Como revertir la apertura automatica de mis nuevos archivos con adobe?

Tags: windows

Lo que me ocurre es lo siguiente, en una ocasion al intentar usar un archivo .whl que no sabia como abrir, mi computador me mostro como opcion adobe, la cuestion es que accidentalmente di click en el boton de usar siempre.

Ahora cada vez que descargo algun archivo que en primera instancia el computador no sabe con que abrir usa abobe y como consecuencia se convierte en un pdf.

Quisiera usar un archivo .whl y uno .ipynb pero ahora no puedo.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Muy fácil:
Haz click con el botón secundario (derecho) del mouse sobre cualquier archivo .whl haz click en *abrir con...* y luego *elegir programa predeterminado* y busca el programa con quieras abrirlo (por ejemplo Python Wheels, IPython, Jupyter, etc.) y finalmente haz click en la casilla *usar siempre el programa seleccionado para abrir este tipo de archivos* y el botón *aceptar* (si el programa no aparece debes hacer click en *examinar* y buscar en la carpeta *archivos de programa* el programa a utilizar (seleccionas obviamente el ejecutable .exe). Espero te sirva...
[image: Botón secundario sobre el archivo] [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]